# Video streaming over simple-peer (WebRTC)

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, video-streaming, simple-peer

I want to make a website (using `NodeJS` and `Express` deployed on `Heroku`) where a user can stream any of his local video (using videojs) to other users connected to each other with simple-peer currently what I got is that I make chunks of the local video and send them over using simple-peer data channels and it works fine for 2 users (I can get more user inter connected but the app crashes if I send data to multiple user at the same time) but something definitely can be a better thing to do other than this way. I looking for other options here and how can I achieve this.

Comment: Yes you can achieve streaming for more than 2 users in simple-peer. here is a link https://github.com/feross/simple-peer explanation given for more than 2 connections and actually I am working with simple peer for more than two peers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe its worth to try [PeerJS](https://peerjs.com), it's a very easy to use WebRTC simplification and also in my experience stable. A connection between more than two users should also be possible.

Comment: is it better that simple-peer ? coz I'm already using simple-peer and i can connect to 2 or more users and the it works for getUsermedia (audio part only) but fails/problem in my code causing it to crash when send chunks of files to multiple users

Comment: i did switch to peerjs, better datachannels for sure